# Hide API Key in Manifest and in source code android

Tags: android, maps, key, proguard

I have a Google MAPS API KEY which can easily be seen when you decompile my app by using reverse engineering. This is not good at all. Also, I am using a Weather API KEY in my source code accessing via string.

I found this website https://medium.com/@cassioso/a-strategy-to-secure-your-api-keys-using-gradle-b9c107272860

and wanted to ask you, if this article is recommended or do you have a better idea?

Does anyone have any experience concerning this issue?

I am using ProGuard, but ProGuard does NOT obfuscate AndroidManifest ( which is even not possible as far as I read ) and it also does not obfuscate any `String` API KEY ( I don't know why)

I don't have any experience with DexGuard.

Can you please tell me if this website is working or can you please give some more tips how to hide api keys in manifest and also in source code.

Comment: related https://security.stackexchange.com/q/153142/84331

Answer (score 9):

There is no reason to hide your API key. They are parsed directly from the manifest. Was just going to comment, not answer, but comment was too long haha. so I guess I'll post as answer.

Why do you want to hide the API key? GMaps and Fabric and Firebase recommend you put directly into your Manfiest.

The website you posted simply puts it in the build.config file. You could also nest in environment variables and pull them in with Gradle, but what's the point. You are still pulling them into a file that will be generated and packaged with the APK. I'm happy to help you find a way to hide your keys, if you can explain your reasoning.

If it is really necessary you could always make it a remote API to pull first time and put in a DB and if it really needs to be secure you could use SQLCipher. Once stored you could load dynamically at runtime. I don't know how well this will work when the SDKs are parsing it from the manifest though.

It is common when you make an SDK to parse your key from the manifest file, so if it is intended to be loaded at runtime, the SDK would have to support that instead of relying on parsing it from the manifest.

So my recommendation is to leave it in manifest as normal visible API key. The package is unique to your app, the SDK will use the package and likely app secret with key nested in SDK to ensure all calls came from your app. So back to my original question. Why do you need to hide the API keys?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Honestly, I can leave the Google MAP API KEY in my Manifest. Why? Because I secured this KEY via Google using SHA-1 Fingerprint. So, using google maps api key for anyone is not possible. 

The problem is the weather api key. Someone can use this api key and the server (OpenWeather) can spot a lot of activity and can block my api key. So the users of my app are not able to use the weather function. That's my problem.

Comment: @Blnpwr You can't hide plain text strings. Best way to get that API key is having a server retrieving it to you after proper authentication. Check out Facebook's Conceal API, it may help too.

Comment: @GuilhE well, connecting to the server requires also a key, which can't be hidden following your logic. It's already bad that reverse engineering can make your api keys visible and if you use a server connection, your password to this server is also visible. I don't think that is a good idea.

Comment: Gotcha, well if they need to be secure, they will not require it to be in the manifest and you can simply retrieve from https server via API and store locally in SQLite if you want for future use. The other option is to encrypt it with encryption that you can unencrypt in your code with a salt that is unique to your app and only you would know to use it. Then you could unencrypt the string at runtime and no one else would know any better

Comment: @Sam thank you. Is there any example using your recommended second option? I am new to this issue.

Comment: By proper authentication I was thinking in some login system (user/pwd), but since this is a weather app (or the weather API it's just a feature?) I guess it's overkill. Try Facebook Conceal ;)
Manually encryption will fail since you'll have to provide a salt, pwd, etc and that will be hardcoded too. Facebook API saves you time. "
Conceal provides easy Android APIs for performing fast encryption and authentication of data. http://facebook.github.io/conceal/"

Comment: @GuilhE the app just offers a weather feature, it's not a weather app. Maybe using an interface or a class, that contains 100 strings and somewhere in the middle of these 100 strings there is my string api key, maybe proguard would obfuscate this class.

Comment: Proguard does not obfuscate plain text or hardcoded strings ;) even NDK will fail to do so.

Comment: @GuilhE well then I think I have to make the overkill version. Using more than 100 strings, and 3 of these 100 strings contain parts of my api key, and  a string from these 100 will be the concated string ;)

Comment: Of course you could have a "letter soup" here you would pick the letters by index and that code algorithm would be obfuscated, but why bother when you could use a good and tested API? ^^

Comment: Just to be sure guys. Using SHA-1 Fingerprint and my package name of the app in Google API Service will prevent other guys using my google mapis api key, right?

Comment: Yes, because only you have access to Google Cloud Console, so only you can add/remove SHA-1 Fingerprint. This is valid for any API service where you use SHA or M5D in their consoles.

Comment: Sam is absolutely right. AndroidManifest.xml is packed into the apk after it was built with all placeholders and values. If you decompile it the file will be 100% readable. You can't hide anything in the Manifest file. The other KEYs may and should be hidden in the native code or in images or with mixed approaches.